# Strategy for Processing a Text File with a Header using Reg Exp in Java

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a file that contains a header with comments (e.g. [Comment] This is a comment) and a subsequent data section. The data starts at "Mk1=".

*The program I am working on should:*

- Copy the header contents
- Search and replace only in the data section of the file
- Write header and data to a new file

*I am currently using:*

- StringBuffer
- Scanner
- regex.Pattern;

In my code so far (reduced to its essentials):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = readFile("file.ext");

    Scanner inputScanner = null;

    try {
        inputScanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String currentLine = "";

    while(inputScanner.hasNext()) {
        currentLine = inputScanner.findInLine(regexpPattern);

        if (currentLine != null){
             fileOutput.append(currentLine + "\n");
        }
    }
```

}

Because the Scanner works like a queue, I have trouble figuring out what strategy I should use. I have found examples of using a Matcher instead of a Scanner. To my understanding I also have to work with boolean flags, because of the queue-like structure of Scanner. The findInHorizon() method does not seem helpful as I want the reg exp only to apply beyond the horizon. Is there perhaps a "hack" for the delimiter of the Scanner, assuming I know the series of characters of the header start and end?

**File Example**

```
[Comment]
Text goes here.

[Another Comment]
;Instructions: Below you will find Mk1= where the data can be assigned.
;More text.

Mk1=data
Mk2=data
Mk3=data
```

What strategy should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use `java.nio.file.Files` (since Java 1.7) and your text file isn't too big, I'd read all lines at once and go for the Matcher:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), charset);

for (String line : lines) {
    Matcher matcher = regexpPattern.matcher(line);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Using regex groups will prove useful for retrieving parameter-value pairs:

```
Pattern dataPattern = Pattern.compile("^Mk(\\d+)=(.*)$");
Matcher dataMatcher = dataPattern.matcher(line);
int mk = Integer.parseInt(dataMatcher.group(1));
String data = dataMatcher.group(2);
```

Comment: This looks promising. The files are roughly 31 kB. Would it be enough to close the InputStream after each file?

Comment: @noumenal I'd certainly consider 31 kB a small file. No need to open or close any file streams, the `Files.readAllLines()` method handles opening and closing of your file, even when something goes wrong, it's a very high-level method which seems appropriate for your task. It may throw an `IOException` like when the file is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing is a two step process: You have a tokenizer which recognizes patterns in the input and a parser which reads tokens but also has a state to know where it is.

You can use regexp for the "tokenize" part of the problem but you also need a parser which remembers "I have seen `[Comment]`" so it knows what could/should be next.

Related:

- https://class.coursera.org/compilers/lecture

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. I am afraid I don't have 18 hours to engage in this material right now. Are there any particular lectures I could focus on to solve the current problem? In the ideal case, I would have a parser that reads the header as a string and a line-by-line parser for the data section. I assume that this would be the most optimal solution.

Comment: You don't need everything; I suggest to do the first 3 and then the first two of chapter 5. Watch the rest when you don't understand something in those videos.